# get column from too many tables in mysql

Tags: mysql, join

.I have too many tables X1,X2,...Xn (they might exceed 75 tables) in Mysql DB to represent departments of a very large company.
every table has structure something like this

```
desc X1;
+---------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field   | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+---------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| ReqF    | int(11)     | Yes  |     | NULL    |       |
| EmpName | varchar(32) | Yes  | MUL | NULL    |       |
```

now I am supposed to return all ReqF from departments that John works in.
I know i can do so by left join like this

```
select X1.ReqF,X2.ReqF,...,Xn.ReqF FROM X1 left join X2 on (EmpName) left join .... left join Xn on X1.EmpName=Xn.EmpName where X1.EmpName='John'
```

is there any better way to do so and what if we need to retrieve different fields from tables (ex X1.ReqF1, X2.ReqF2 or random number of fields from tables like [SELECT X1.F1, X1.F2, X2.F3,...])??

Comment: No, not with that design. Well you could do a Union instead of Join but you'll still have to reference all tables.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If all the tables use the MyISAM Storage Engine and have the same table structure, I have some good news for you.

You can create a single table that consumes no additional space except a `.frm` file and some mapping info. The key is to take advantage of the [**MERGE (MRG_MyISAM) Storage Engine**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/merge-storage-engine.html).

Here is how you can do this:

```
CREATE TABLE XMerge LIKE X1;
ALTER TABLE XMerge ENGINE=MRG_MYISAM
UNION=(X1,X2,X3,X4) INSERT_METHOD=LAST;
```

Using this method, you can query the 4 tables at the same time like this:

```
SELECT ReqF FROM XMerge WHERE EmpName='John';
```

Was that simple, or what ???

In your case, you have 75 tables. You would do this:

```
CREATE TABLE XMerge LIKE X1;
ALTER TABLE XMerge ENGINE=MRG_MYISAM
UNION=(X1,X2,X3,X4,X5,X6,X7,X8,X9,
X10,X11,X12,X13,X14,X15,X16,X17,X18,X19,
X20,X21,X22,X23,X24,X25,X26,X27,X28,X29,
X30,X31,X32,X33,X34,X35,X36,X37,X38,X39,
X40,X41,X42,X43,X44,X45,X46,X47,X48,X49,
X50,X51,X52,X53,X54,X55,X56,X57,X58,X59,
X60,X61,X62,X63,X64,X65,X66,X67,X68,X69,
X70,X71,X72,X73,X74,X75) INSERT_METHOD=LAST;
SELECT ReqF FROM XMerge WHERE EmpName='John';
```

The beauty of this is that creating a MERGE table takes milliseconds. Just make sure every table has an index on EmpName. Better to do 75 indexed lookups that 75 full table scans. If there is no index on EmpName, you need to do this:

```
ALTER TABLE X1 ADD UNIQUE KEY (EmpName);
ALTER TABLE X2 ADD UNIQUE KEY (EmpName);
.
.
.
ALTER TABLE X75 ADD UNIQUE KEY (EmpName);
CREATE TABLE XMerge LIKE X1;
ALTER TABLE XMerge ENGINE=MRG_MYISAM
UNION=(X1,X2,X3,X4,X5,X6,X7,X8,X9,
X10,X11,X12,X13,X14,X15,X16,X17,X18,X19,
X20,X21,X22,X23,X24,X25,X26,X27,X28,X29,
X30,X31,X32,X33,X34,X35,X36,X37,X38,X39,
X40,X41,X42,X43,X44,X45,X46,X47,X48,X49,
X50,X51,X52,X53,X54,X55,X56,X57,X58,X59,
X60,X61,X62,X63,X64,X65,X66,X67,X68,X69,
X70,X71,X72,X73,X74,X75) INSERT_METHOD=LAST;
SELECT ReqF FROM XMerge WHERE EmpName='John';
```

Give it a Try !!!

Answer (score 0):

Given this table structure I'd do:

```
      SELECT ReqF FROM X1 WHERE EmpName='John'
UNION SELECT ReqF FROM X2 WHERE EmpName='John'
UNION SELECT ReqF FROM X3 WHERE EmpName='John'
UNION SELECT ReqF FROM X4 WHERE EmpName='John'
...
UNION SELECT ReqF FROM Xn WHERE EmpName='John'
```

because that would bring the ReqF values in a more consistent structure (same column).

Comment: Always use `UNION ALL` or use `UNION DISTINCT` when you consciously want de-duplication. It's faster, but more importantly it prevents accidentally losing rows.